# What is the correct way to approach ViewPager and Fragments when number of fragments are more than 50 but each of them has same layout and methods?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am making an app which has a navigation drawer. This navigation drawer has 50 menu items. These items have the same layout, same activity but different data. 
I want to implement ViewPager in my app so that the user could swipe left and right (manually and automatically).

Issue: I am facing an issue of how to implement this. The activity (for these menu items) has its own methods and functionality. A ViewPager can slide fragments but my issue is that since all of these menu items have the same layout and functionality then it would be much better to use one fragment whose data change with swipes for each menu items.

I don't know how to approach this. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using a recycleView,and you will need an arrayAdapter which will help you adapt the data accordingly and you will need to have a separate class that will have all the data you want, you can also have different constructor in that class. You can check this to know more https://www.codexpedia.com/android/a-very-simple-example-of-android-recyclerview/